# Incorrect type of `this` within schema virtual definition

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to create a virtual on a subdocument schema which returns whether or not the size of an array field of that schema (`items`) is bigger than 15.

```
import { Schema, Types } from 'mongoose';
import itemSchema, { type Item } from './item';

export interface Shop {
    items: Types.DocumentArray<Item>;
}

export default new Schema<Shop>(
    {
        items: {
            type: [itemSchema],
            required: true
        }
    },
    {
        virtuals: {
            isFull: {
                get(): boolean {
                    return this.items.length > 15;
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

TypeScript throws:

[image]

I've double checked the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) but couldn't find a solution

Comment: What's the version of mongoose are you using?